# Failed sending mail through google api with javascript

Tags: javascript, email, google-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to send an email through Google API with JavaScript.

My issue is that when I try to send a simple mail with no attachments, I get the following error:

> 'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required`

My code

```
function sendMessage() {
gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function() {
    // Web-safe base64 
    var to = 'someone@someone.nl',
        subject = 'Hello World',
        content = 'send a Gmail.'

    var base64EncodedEmail = btoa(
          "Content-Type:  text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" +
          "Content-length: 5000\n" +
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: message/rfc2822\n" +
          "to: someone@someone.nl\n" +
          "from: \"test\" <test@gmail.com>\n" +
          "subject: Hello world\n\n" +

          "The actual message text goes here"
            ).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

    var mail= base64EncodedEmail;
    console.log(mail);
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
      'userId': "me",
      'message': {
          'raw': mail
        }
    });
    request.execute(function(response){
     console.log(response);
   });
  });        

}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546142/gmail-api-for-sending-mails-in-node-js/

Comment: Can you please explain why `replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')` ••• Replacing `+` with `-` and `/` with `_`? Also to simplify use `'` (single quote) to avoid escaping `"`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After days i had found the answer by my own. The problem was that the 'message' in the body only can be used when you send an attachment in the email.

If you have no attachment the query looks like I wrote down here

```
var mail= base64EncodedEmail;
console.log(mail);
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
  'userId': "me",
  'resource': {
      'raw': mail
    }
});
request.execute(function(response){
 console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I find it inconsistent that ```drafts.create``` and ```message.send``` are not using the same syntax...

Comment: is there a python version for this?

Comment: Python 3.8:
    raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()
    gmail_api.users().messages().send(userId= "me", body = {'raw': raw}).execute()